# How To Assign Values Of Array To Another Based On Search Criteria?

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello Everybody i have a question i have an array like this

```
  array 1 =[
    {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
    {title: 'yes', time: "00:02:50"},
    {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
    {title: 'no', time: "02:01:00"},
    {title: 'yes', time: "02:01:50"},
    {title: 'no', time: "10:01:50"},
];
```

i want to filter this array in angular2 or js by title to another array `array2` to be like this

```
array2 = [
   {
    title :'yes',
    count:4,
    values:[
        {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
        {title: 'yes', time: "00:02:50"},
        {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
        {title: 'yes', time: "02:01:50"},
        ]
  },
  {
    title :'no',
    count:2,
    values:[
         {title: 'no', time: "02:01:00"},
         {title: 'no', time: "10:01:50"},
        ]
  }
];
```

where the `name is the name of repeated title in the array1` and `count is the number of repeated object by title` and `values` to store all repeated objects by title

so after filter i want the result like this

```
array1=[
    {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
    {title: 'no', time: "00:02:50"},
   ];
```

and

```
array2 = [
    {
       title :'yes',
       count:4,
       values:[
          {title: 'yes', time: "00:02:50"},
          {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
          {title: 'yes', time: "02:01:50"},
        ]
     },
     {
       title :'no',
       count:2,
       values:[
          {title: 'no', time: "10:01:50"}
        ];
    }
 ];
```

For more Explanation i'm building a website in angular 2 like [toggl timer](https://www.toggl.com/app/timer) as u can see here in the pic [image: My website] so when i click on play button and pause it another object with the input value `title` and time `timer value` is added to array 1 and here is my angular2 code

```
startPlay(name:string = "", time:string = "00:00:00") {
    this.taskInputvalue.next('');
    this.play.next(true);
    this.pause.next(false);
    this.timer.next("00:00:00");
    clearInterval(this.countup);
    //push the task to array
    if(name == "") {
    name = "Add description";
    this.tasks.push({title: name, time: time});
    } else {
    name = name;
    this.tasks.push({title: name, time: time});
    }
}
```

but when i repeat the task name like in the pic the result displayed below each other so what i want if typed `task 1` for first time it shows as a `li` but when a repeat it again it should stored in another array so a can loop through it and show the values below the exsisting li when i click on it please visit [toggl timer](https://www.toggl.com/app/timer)
 to understand what i mean

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Whilst doable this is completely unnecessary  and just boggles down the code, also, what @palaѕн said.

Comment: @palaѕн i updated the question please check it out

Comment: @Dellirium i updated the question please check it out

Comment: I still have no idea what you want to do with the arrays. You have a set of 6 entries in your array set, you want to create a new set of X entries where X is the number of different `title` entries and count is the number of occurances of that entires, that much i gather, but... then you go like "So when i filter i need array 1 to be like: " and you give us 2 entries instead of 6 again, so what happened to array 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explain what you need better, then i can assist you further if this is not what you wanted since I do not understand what you want, I am going to write what I understood you needed, if this is not the case, comment and we will resolve it, but try to be more clear in your future posts.

```
var input = [
    {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
    {title: 'yes', time: "00:02:50"},
    {title: 'yes', time: "00:01:50"},
    {title: 'no', time: "02:01:00"},
    {title: 'yes', time: "02:01:50"},
    {title: 'no', time: "10:01:50"},
];

function getData(arr) {
  var results = {};
  var resultArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(el) {
        if (results[el.title]){
        results[el.title].count++;
      results[el.title].values.push(el);
    }else {
        results[el.title] = {
        title: el.title,
        count: 1,
        values: [el]
      };
    }
  })
  for (o in results){
    resultArr.push(results[o]);
  }
  return resultArr;
}

var output = getData(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array1 and array2 are objetcs you can try this solution:
Let's say that your array1 is now renamed as array, and array2 is now newArray1 and newArray2

```
newArray1: YourArray1ObjectTypo = [];
newArray2: YourArray2ObjectTypo = [];

// function to add the array
insertInArray2() {
  for (a1 in array) {
    if (a1.title == 'yes') {
      newArray1.push(a1);
    }
    else {
      newArray2.push(a1);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit-01: Use global arrays in your class so you don't need to return anything.

Comment: No i don't Know the Value Of The Title So it Will Be a Variable Please see My Question Above And What Is The Formula That I Want

Comment: your question is really confuse.

Comment: please Visit toggl.com and see what happens when u repeat a task name twice regardless the time and compare the result with my picture thanks i appreciate your patience

Comment: Put your code in https://plnkr.co/ so no body need to login or create any account to see it